# Distance Units of a Layer

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in, arcgis-desktop

I am developing an ArcGIS desktop addin. I am attempting to get the distance units (ft, mm, km, etc.) from a layer in my .mxd and display it on a windows form. How can I do this? I can access the distance units of a map by using IMap.DistanceUnits, but I have had trouble accessing the distance units of an individual layer.

Comment: What type of feature are you wanting to measure distance of (point, line, or polygon)?

Comment: It can be a point, line or polygon layer. I only need the map units that the layer exists in (i.e. whether the layer coordinate system is in ft^2, or m^2, or km^2).  I don't need to measure the distance of the features.

Comment: Did you try [IProjectedCoordinateSystem.CoordinateUnit](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000002z5000000)?

Comment: This did the trick! I had to do a bit of casting to get to it, but since I was dealing with the SpatialReference class, which IProjectedCoordinateSystem inherits from, it was no big deal.